# Can DELETE FROM be used inside of a CTE?

Tags: sql-server

Can a `DELETE FROM`, with `OUTPUT` clause, be used inside of a CTE?

Either it's not allowed or I've got the syntax wrong. It'd be very handy to be able to capture deleted rows in a CTE, like below ...

```
WITH DeletedItems AS (
  DELETE FROM Foo
  OUTPUT DELETED.*
)
SELECT *
FROM DeletedItems
```

Redundant example, but it'd be handy to be able to use those deleted items to perhaps further fetch other rows, etc, as part of additional CTEs.

Comment: You can't. You can output the deleted to a temp table and use it in your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not allowed in SQL Server. If you try you will get:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DELETE'

You can use like below. CTE is not required at all.

```
CREATE table Foo
(
    Name varchar(10),
    GroupId varchar(2)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b')
GO

DELETE FROM Foo 
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE GroupId = 'b'
```

Output:

```
Name       GroupId
---------- -------
B          b

(1 row affected)
```